# How to concatenate a hash value and a string

Tags: ruby, string

I am trying to write my hash value into the variable as a concatenated string.

```
original_string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
cipher_key = "honeyL"
message_string = "hEllo world"

deleted_string = original_string.delete!(cipher_key)

altered_string = cipher_key + deleted_string

encryption_hash = Hash.new

i = 0
while(i < original_string.length) 
  encryption_hash [original_string[i]] = altered_string[i].to_s
  i += 1
end

encrypted_message = ""
count = 0

while(count < message_string.length)
  if(message_string[count] == " ")
    encrypted_message << message_string[count]
  else
    encrypted_message << encryption_hash[message_string[count]] 
  end
  count += 1
end

puts encrypted_message
```

I have a problem on line 24, but I don't know why. If I use the `encryption_hash[original_string[count]]` instead of `encryption_hash[message_string[count]]`, then it would work. But I do not know why. Please explain.

Comment: Unrelated, but this isn't very Ruby-like code. Hopefully your instructor isn't teaching you Ruby like it's C or older Java. In any case-debug. Step through the code. Print out values. Check your assumptions.

Comment: To expand on  what @DaveNewton said. Using a while loop with a counter is pretty much never the right thing to do in ruby. Instead use `original_string.each` Look up ruby each to get an idea how it works.

Comment: What do you mean you are unble to concatenate? Does it give you an error? If so what error? Does it give you the wrong value? Write out what you expect to happen and what is currently happening and people will be able to help you better.

Comment: Your hash does not have the key `"h"`, so hash lookup resuls in `nil`, which can't be concatenated.

Comment: "I hava a problem on line 24" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to posting to stack overflow. I am getting a "Can't convert type nil to string (Typerror)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this should help get you on the right track. I'm not 100% sure on the desired outcome of your project, however here is a quick original vs. re-write and explanation of what was happening to you.

#### Original (annotated)

```
original_string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
cipher_key = "honeyL"
message_string = "hEllo world"

# Using the delete! method is actually altering the original_string in memory. You want to use the plane delete method.
deleted_string = original_string.delete!(cipher_key)

altered_string = cipher_key + deleted_string

# This is a fair amount of code for a simple mapping
encryption_hash = Hash.new

i = 0
while(i < original_string.length) 
  encryption_hash [original_string[i]] = altered_string[i].to_s
  i += 1
end

encrypted_message = ""
count = 0

# Because you deleted the message characters from the original_string BEFORE creating you encryption_hash, you're getting null value on the look up.
while(count < message_string.length)
  if(message_string[count] == " ")
    encrypted_message << message_string[count]
  else
    encrypted_message << encryption_hash[message_string[count]] 
  end
  count += 1
end

puts encrypted_message
```

#### Rewrite

```
base_str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
message = 'hEllo world'
key = 'honeyL'

# Using delete instead of delete!
altered_str = key + base_str.delete(key)

# Zip together characters and create hash from grouped array
encryption_hash = Hash[base_str.chars.zip(altered_str.chars)]
encryption_hash[' '] = ' '

encrypted_message = ''

# Loop through non-inclusive range concatenating encrypted values to string
for i in 0...message.length
  encrypted_message << encryption_hash[message[i]]
end

puts encrypted_message
```

#### UPDATE

I went through some of the suggested iterators to see which performed best and all were relatively the same (using an 8,145,000 character message):

```
  encrypted_message = message.gsub(/./) { |chr| encryption_hash[chr] }
  # {"ruby":"2.3.0","elapsed_time":3.24,"garbage_collection":"on","memory_used":"8 MB","garbage_collection_count":456}

  message.each_char { |m| encrypted_message << encryption_hash[m] }
  # {"ruby":"2.3.0","elapsed_time":2.06,"garbage_collection":"on","memory_used":"8 MB","garbage_collection_count":456}

  (0...message.length).each { |i| encrypted_message << encryption_hash[message[i]]  }
  # {"ruby":"2.3.0","elapsed_time":2.21,"garbage_collection":"on","memory_used":"8 MB","garbage_collection_count":456}

  for i in 0...message.length
    encrypted_message << encryption_hash[message[i]]
  end
  # {"ruby":"2.3.0","elapsed_time":2.21,"garbage_collection":"on","memory_used":"8 MB","garbage_collection_count":456}
```

That said, I found out that `gsub` can take a hash as its second parameter for substitution mappings on matched characters. This performed right in the same ballpark.

```
  message.gsub!(/[a-zA-Z]/, encryption_hash)
  # {"ruby":"2.3.0","elapsed_time":2.45,"garbage_collection":"on","memory_used":"8 MB","garbage_collection_count":388}
```

At the end of the day, I think this is the best solution. The reason is that it does NOT require the original string to be pre-formatted, as well as doesn't lose any unmapped values. For example, in the original answers, any punctuation marks or numbers would be omitted and lost. With this `gsub` approach, you can only encrypt the character sets you to want to encrypt, leaving the rest unchanged.

This simplifies the solution to:

```
base_str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
message = 'hEllo world'
key = 'honeyL'

altered_str = key + base_str.delete(key)

encryption_hash = Hash[base_str.chars.zip(altered_str.chars)]

message.gsub!(/[a-zA-Z]/, encryption_hash)

puts message
```

Comment: This is good. I think one small improvement; If you add a mapping of blank => blank in the encryption hash, you can drop the if statement. I wonder if we could do a `map` vs. the `for` as well...

Comment: That makes sense. It would be an improvement. The issue with map would be it using up more memory. Ie... splitting the string into an array and the creating a variable for each element during the iteration. Using the for loop here is just faster.

Comment: If someone really didn't like the for loop, I'd suggest using inject/reduce instead of map.

Comment: `(0...message.length).each do |index|`? `message.each_char { |m| encrypted_message << encryption_hash[m] }`? `encrypted_message = message.gsub(/./) { |chr| encryption_hash[chr] }`?

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure how to upvote this answer but that makes sense. I appreciate all of you for helping me find my solution!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error on this line:

```
encrypted_message << encryption_hash[message_string[count]]
```

Because `message_string[count]` returns `h` (from your `hEllo world`, but your `encryption_hash` is a Hash without an `h` key. Nor does it have `honeyL` characters in it.

When you called `original_string.delete!(cipher_key)`, the `delete!` mutated the `original_string`, removing the 6 characters from your `cipher_key`

The reason swapping original string for message string works:

```
pry >> original_string
=> "abcdfgijklmpqrstuvwxzABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
pry >> message_string
=> "hEllo world"
```

In your example, `count` is 0 (you're on your first iteration), so it's looking for the 0 index of it. The 0 index of `original_string` is `a`, which IS present in your `encryption_hash`. The 0 index of `message_string` is `h`, which IS NOT present in your `encryption_hash`.

I'm not sure what a solution might be, because I'm not sure of the desired outcome. But that's where/why it's breaking. To debug it, you can try `gem install pry pry-byebug`, then at the top of your ruby file, add:

```
require 'pry'
require 'pry-byebug
```

Then, on a new line after your `else` statement, add `binding.pry`. Run your script and it will "stop" on that line. You can inspect all the variables at that point using `puts`.

Use `exit` to quit pry, and use `whereami` to reset the view of where you were stopped in the code. You can also use `play -l <line number>` to evaluate a line.

[image: pry example]